# Cross platform module system

Tags: node.js, module, setter, defineproperty

Edit: In interest of trying to figure out a solution, I edited the post to explain more clearly of what I'm trying to accomplish.

**I am trying to re-invent the wheel, with minimal amount of code to create a cross platform async module loading system**

This should ideally work on any ES5 runtime engine, however the primary targets are node.js and browser.

What I'm trying to accomplish is creating a global object with a setter, from which the object being set is the module contents. Node.js accomplishes this with `module.exports = {}` and I'm trying to replicate this behavior.

The issue i'm having is interesting because the global setter does not create a 1:1 mapping of the module filename and the exported object.

**First attempt:**

So far I've tried binding a setter to be specific to a particular function call. It's always resorting to the last `module` being loaded. I thought by wrapping the setter in a closure, it would keep the `module` parameters in the call stack but I was mistaken - since the setter changes.

**An improved solution but not quite there yet:**

I've also tried to use the `name` property defined in the exported object to create this mapping, but has proven to be ineffective and easy to circumvent. I.E. by exporting a name that is not true to what it does, and can intentionally or unintentionally overwrite other modules in the system.

**Here's some example code:**

```
let exporter = {}
global.exporter = exporter

const imports = function(module, callback) {
  return new (function(module, callback) {
    Object.defineProperty(exporter, 'exports', {
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true,
      set: function(exportFile) {
        console.log('Setting export file:', exportFile.name, ':', module)
        callback(exportFile)
      },
    })

    console.log('loading module: ', module)
    require(module)
  })(module, callback)
}
```

**Using setter in module file:**

```
exporter.exports = {
  name: 'File1',
}
```

**Example code that uses the new import.**

```
function load(name) {
  imports(__dirname + '/modules/' + name, function(exportFile) {
    console.log('Module loaded: ', exportFile.name)
  })
}

load('1') // instant
load('2') // 2 second timeout
load('3') // 1 second timeout
```

Output:

```
loading module:  .../modules/1
Setting export file: File1 : .../modules/1
Module loaded:  File1
loading module:  .../modules/2
loading module:  .../modules/3
Setting export file: File3 : .../modules/3
Module loaded:  File3
Setting export file: File2 : .../modules/3
Module loaded:  File2
```

I appreciate any help that could fix this context issue!

I am also open to any other suggestions to accomplish this same task, without using anything node-specific, as I plan to make this cross platform compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm trying to accomplish is creating a global object with a setter, from which the object being set is the module contents. Node.js accomplishes this with `module.exports = {}` and I'm trying to replicate this behavior.

**Your problem is that you *are indeed* using a *global object*. Since the modules are loading asynchronously, the global object may be in an incorrect state when a module executes.** There may be a way to reset the global object after your `require` call so that *your specific example* works fine, but there are cases that it won't cover, and you'll be playing whack-a-mole with bugs for a long time.

Although `module` looks like a global object, it is in fact an object created anew for each module. The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) is explicit about this:

> [Node.js] helps to provide some global-looking variables that are actually specific to the module, such as:
>
> - The `module` and `exports` objects that the implementor can use to export values from the module.
> - The convenience variables `__filename` and `__dirname`, containing the module's absolute filename and directory path.

Providing your modules with independent objects to modify will make the code much simpler *overall*.

Above the part of the documentation I cited above, you find:

> Before a module's code is executed, Node.js will wrap it with a
>   function wrapper that looks like the following:
>
> ```
> (function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
> // Module code actually lives in here 
> });
> ```

You could take a page from it and have a wrapper like:

```
(function (exporter, ...) {
// Module code here...
});
```

Here's an illustration:

```es6
    const source = `
    exporter.exports = {
      SomeVar: "Some Value",
    };
    `;

    function wrapInFunction(source) {
      return `(function (exporter) { ${source} })`;
    }

    const exporter = {
      exports: {},
    };

    eval(wrapInFunction(source))(exporter);
    console.log(exporter);
```

A note on the use of `eval` here. You've probably heard "eval is evil". That's true, *as far as it goes*. The saying is there to remind people that `const x = /* value from some user input */; eval('table.' + x );` is both unnecessary (since you can do `table[x]`) and dangerous because the user input is evaluated raw and you do not trust the user input to *run arbitrary code*. A user would set `x` to something that does nefarious things. Using `eval` is still warranted in some cases, like the case here. In a browser you could avoid `eval` by shoving the source into a `script` and listening to the `load` event but you've gained nothing security-wise. Then again that's platform-specific. If you are in Node.js you can use the [`vm` module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html), but it comes with this disclaimer "**The vm module is not a security mechanism. Do not use it to run untrusted code.**" And it is also platform-specific.

---

By the way, your current code is not cross-platform. Your code depends on the `require` call, which is available only on some platforms. (It is notably not present on browsers without loading additional modules.) I suspect you put that there as a placeholder for functionality to be developed later but I thought I'd mention it nonetheless since cross-platform support is one of your goals.

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate the very lengthy answer and such a great solution! 

I'm aware that `require` is for node only, the function in my application actually takes care of the `require` for me and is platform agnostic. 

I'll award you the bounty however what would REALLY sweeten the deal would be to create a node `require` shim that uses the same path lookups (including package.json support). I could then wrap the code using fs modules and the IIFE idea you provided. Would you happen to have a reference how this path lookup procedure for `node_modules` is handled?

Comment: In my last comment, I didn't mean for you to create said `require` shim. I just meant learning about the `node_modules` resolution, however after a bit of research found the answer I was looking for. Accepting this as the answer. Genius solution!